# Firebase fetch user data - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I want to fetch data, I have done this multiple times but for some reason it is not working and I see no reason as to why.

My code for fetching the data

```
func fetchCurrentUserInfo() {

    let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser!
    let currentUserRef = dataBaseRef.child("users").child(currentUser.uid)

    currentUserRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        let user = UserClass(snapshot: snapshot)
        self.downloadImageFromFirebase(urlString: user.photoURL!)
        self.userName.text = user.getFullName()

        //SD Cache
        self.userProfileImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: user.photoURL!), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "UserImageTemplate"))

    }) { (error) in
        let alert = SCLAlertView()
        _ = alert.showError("OOPS!", subTitle: error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

My user class file

```
struct UserClass {

        var firstName: String?
        var email: String?
        var photoURL: String?
        var uid: String?
        var ref: DatabaseReference!
        var key: String?
        var lastName: String?
        var accountType: String?

        init(snapshot: DataSnapshot){

            key = snapshot.key
            ref = snapshot.ref
            accountType = (snapshot.value! as! NSDictionary)["Account Type"] as? String
            firstName = (snapshot.value! as! NSDictionary)["First Name"] as? String
            email = (snapshot.value! as! NSDictionary)["email"] as? String
            uid = (snapshot.value! as! NSDictionary)["uid"] as? String
            photoURL = (snapshot.value! as! NSDictionary)["photoURL"] as? String
            lastName = (snapshot.value! as! NSDictionary)["Last Name"] as? String
        }

        func getFullName() -> String {
            return ("\(firstName!) \(lastName!)")
        }

    }
}
```

I have set the read and write rules to true. When I call the fetchCurrentUserInfo function, it returns all the data for the first name, last name, key, etc. but it returns the photo URL, UID or email as nil giving me the error: fatal error: `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your crash log says it all. You're trying to force unwrap an optional variable by `as!` casting. Make sure you have valid values in your `snapshot`.

Also, a better model would like so, this is safer:

```
    struct UserClass {

        var firstName: String!
        var email: String!
        var photoURL: String!
        var uid: String!
        var ref: DatabaseReference!
        var key: String!
        var lastName: String!
        var accountType: String!

        init?(snapshot: DataSnapshot?) {

            guard let value = snapshot?.value as? [String: AnyObject],
                let accountType = value["Account Type"] as? String,
                let firstName = value["First Name"] as? String,
                let email = value["email"] as? String,
                let uid = value["uid"] as? String,
                let photoURL = value["photoURL"] as? String,
                let lastName = value["Last Name"] as? String else {
                    return nil
            }

            self.key = snapshot?.key
            self.ref = snapshot?.ref
            self.accountType = accountType
            self.firstName = firstName
            self.email = email
            self.uid = uid
            self.photoURL = photoURL
            self.lastName = lastName
        }

        func getFullName() -> String {
            return ("\(firstName!) \(lastName!)")
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now if I breakpoint and PO snapshot, it returns the user's data. However, I try to assign this to a variable like so:

    let user = UserClass(snapshot: currentUser)!

and then PO user in the debug console. However, the data returns as "Some" and crashes when trying to assign user.photoURL as the data is unreadable or nil.

Cheers.

Comment: Wait, just realised it was down to the capitalisation on "PhotoURL"